# componentWillReceiveProps method doesn't run anymore when using redux to call api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm going to call api using `redux`: 
I used `axios`,`history`,`react-redux`,`react-router-native`,`react-router`,,`redux-promise-middleware`,`redux-thunk` component to make api call using `redux`:
I made `Reducers` folder and put all my reducer file there in their own file and combine them in a main file like this
this is my **generateoptReducer.js** file:

```
const initialState = {
    data: {},
    error: null,
    status: null
};
import {generateOTP} from '../Actions/api';
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case (action.type === 'GENERATEOTP_PENDING' || {}).input:
            // Action is pending (request is in progress)
            return {...state, status: 'fetching',methodes:'done1'};
        case (action.type === 'GENERATEOTP_FULFILLED' || {}).input:
            // Action is fulfilled (request is successful/promise resolved)
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                data: action.payload.data,
                status: 'success',
                methodes:'done1'
            };
            case 'generateOTP':
                // Action is fulfilled (request is successful/promise resolved)
                return {
                    ...state,
                    error: null,
                    data: action.payload.data,
                    status: 'success',
                    methodes:'done1'
                };
        case (action.type === 'GENERATEOTP_REJECTED' || {}).input:
            // Action is rejected (request failed/promise rejected)
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload,
                status: 'error'
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

And combine them in the **index.js** file:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

//import api from './api-reducer';


import generateotp from './generateotpReducer';
import login from './loginReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  generateotp,
  login,
  routing: routerReducer,
});
```

I also made another folder named `Action` and put all my api in a file named **api.js**:

This is my above reducer action:

```
export const generateOTP = (phone_number) => ({
    type: 'GENERATEOTP',
    payload: axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: format(generate_endpoint, phone_number, serviceId),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json","Content-Type":"application/json"}
    })
});
```

this is also my store:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import reducers from './Reducers';

export default function configureStore(history) {
  const middleware = applyMiddleware(
    promiseMiddleware(),
    thunk,

    routerMiddleware(history));
  return createStore(reducers, {}, middleware);
}
```

and this is the way I dispatch the action:
imported like this in above of my component file:

```
import { generateOTP } from "../Components/Actions/api";
```

and dispatch the action like this:

```
this.props.dispatch(generateOTP(formatted_phone_number));
```

I also connect the component like this in the bottom of the file:

```
export default connect(state => state)(SignIn)
```

Now I need  the result of this api. I used to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` method to receive the result. I don't know why this component doesn't run. I searched too much I a find a confused result which said the state doesn't change then the `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't run!!! the good thing is that the api call successfully and i can see the log and i can see the `%cGENERATEOTP_PENDING` and then `%cGENERATEOTP_FULFILLED` in the log and api call successfully but the problem is with the `componentWillReceiveProps`(that doesn't run any more) which I used to receive the result of the api call.

Comment: Sorry if my question is dumb, which file would you actually deploy `componentWillReceiveProps`, it's always good to provide enough information, but this one is hard to trace. Maybe you could reorganize it to help people who want to give a hand.

Comment: Have you used Provider, how are you creating the store and where exactly do you have componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for reply, i shared my whole project in this path https://github.com/Husseinoj/reactapi

Comment: @Carr thanks, i shared the project in my github, the project worked well when i called only one api

Comment: I checked out the project, `componentWillReceiveProps` is getting called, but I cant resolve the `api` since it is pointing to your server maybe.

Comment: yes it's a local host server, okay i'll do it with another online api soon. it's a dommy ruby localhost app which only has two api, i tested the api with postman, it was good and in factit just a test, you know i have big problem with calling multi api in one component,

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps ` is getting called, what is the final solution that you want to receive?

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement looks mailformed

`case (action.type === 'GENERATEOTP_FULFILLED' || {}).input:`

This will never run, because `(action.type === 'GENERATEOTP_FULFILLED' || {})` will be either `true`, either `{}`, and `?.input` will be always `undefined`

You need to write smth like this to validate some additional parameters:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'GENERATEOTP_PENDING':
        if (action.input) {
            // Action is pending (request is in progress)
            return {...state, status: 'fetching',methodes:'done1'};
        }
        break; //!
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps){

console.log('get here',nextProps. fullState)

}
```

**use connect like this**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
console.log('get your state here',state)
  return {
   fullState: state.appState,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {generateOTP})(SignIn);
```

Comment: but i mapped  the state to props like this export default connect(state => state)(SignIn)

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer code looks a bit off. You have:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case (action.type === 'GENERATEOTP_PENDING' || {}).input:
      // Action is pending (request is in progress)
      return {...state, status: 'fetching',methodes:'done1'};
  case (action.type === 'GENERATEOTP_FULFILLED' || {}).input:
      // Action is fulfilled (request is successful/promise resolved)
      return {
          ...state,
          error: null,
          data: action.payload.data,
          status: 'success',
          methodes:'done1'
      };
  case 'generateOTP':
      // Action is fulfilled (request is successful/promise resolved)
      return {
          ...state,
          error: null,
          data: action.payload.data,
          status: 'success',
          methodes:'done1'
      };
  // ... etc
}
```

The switch statement is looking at `action.type`, then the first two cases try to access `(action.type === 'ACTION_NAME' || {}).input`. This statement either resolves to `(a Boolean instance).input`, or `{}.input`. Each of these cases will be "falsey", because `input` is not a property on any of those values. When the code runs the program will be comparing `action.type` to `(false || {}).input`, which will never be true, and as such that case will not be run.

I am not sure what you are trying to compute in the first two cases there, but the next case in the switch statement looks more correct, where you just have an action name as a string (`case 'generateOTP'`).

My assumption is that your reducer code never runs, even though the network request does.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer mentioned your "reducer" file looks quite weird.

A switch case should be

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'GENERATEOTP_PENDING':
    //stuff
    break;
  case 'GENERATEOTP_FULFILLED':
    //stuff
    break;
  case 'generateOTP':
    //stuff
    break;
```

but another issue I think we have is that the action of "generateOTP"
is setting a "promise" inside the action to redux.

The reducer handles that like its a normal data object.

I would handle the promise of my action
or at least make sure the reducers is handling that promise.

Comment: he is using redux-promise-middleware which will take care of the promise in the payload. redux-proimise-middleware despatch actions accordingly when the promise is resolved. and the reducer should always  be side effects free. so handling your peomise inside reducer is an anti-pattern in my opinion

Comment: I don't handle it in the reducer :) I just said he should handle in the action but if he really wants he could do that in the reducer. I use redux saga and thunk

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your action as per below.

```
export function generateOTP() {
 return {
  type: 'GENERATE_OTP',
  payload:axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/news',
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
  }).then(success => {
    return success
  }).catch(fail => {
    return fail
 })
}
```

As per the above comments the reducer must be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to dispatch an action not through this.props.dispatch but with just dispatch(generateOTP)

if you want this action to be avaliable in your props, then in connect method you have to fullfill mapDispatchToProps function.

In my code for example:

```
import * as postActions from '../actions/post'
import * as langActions from '../actions/lang'

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(Object.assign({},
     postActions,
     langActions,
  ), dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(News)
```

However, even if it's is your case then you access this action not through dispatch, but as any other fucntions from your props:

```
this.props.generateOTP()
```